# Selecting None-s from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select a column of values where the corresponding column has `None` in it.

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
tdf = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'a':'val', 'b':'abc'},
    {'a':None, 'b':'def'}])
```

Since the following works for values:

```
In [112]: tdf[tdf['a']=='val']
Out[112]: 
     a    b
0  val  abc
```

I was expecting the same to work for `None`, but it doesn't:

```
In [111]: tdf[tdf['a']==None]
Out[111]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

In the end I'd like to use something like `tdf[tdf['a']==None]['b']`, but how do I handle those `None` values properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) to test for `NaN`:

```
In [71]:
tdf[tdf.isnull()]

Out[71]:
      a    b
0   NaN  NaN
1  None  NaN
```

`NaN` has the property that it is not equal to itself which is why it failed for you:

```
In [72]:
np.NaN == np.NaN

Out[72]:
False

In [73]:
np.NaN != np.NaN

Out[73]:
True
```

it is also available as a method on a [series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html#pandas.Series.isnull):

```
In [74]:
tdf[tdf['a'].isnull()]

Out[74]:
      a    b
1  None  def
```

So to do what you specifically want, you can pass the boolean mask from `isnull` to `loc` and select column 'b':

```
In [75]:
tdf.loc[tdf['a'].isnull(), 'b']

Out[75]:
1    def
Name: b, dtype: object
```